# Ensure user selects item from filtered <UL> in an html form

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I have an html form with multiple `<input>` tags (Name, date, time, ordernumber, task, notes are the main inputs).
In the ordernumber input, when the user starts typing, a `<ul>` appears and is filtered based on what the user types into the ordernumber input.
I want them to select from the list before moving to the next field.  This is for data validation reasons. So if they type `mee` in the input, `MEETINGS` will appear in the list. `mee` is not valid data for when the form is submitted.

`onblur=function()` doesn't work - it shows the list without being filtered when the form is loaded.
`document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('blur', function() {}` along with `document.getElementById('myUL').orderlistElement.querySelector('li.active')` sort of works as it detects that a selection hasn't been made. It tells the user (via an `alert()`) that they have left the input box without making a selection, but they have to leave the box to make the selection so it comes up everytime.

I perform validation on the form inputs upon submission, but I will like to bring the issue to attention of the user at the point it occurs.

I can't even think of the logic, before I even attempt the code. Maybe there is an industry term for what I am trying to achieve.

It's something like:

1. check user has left the `<input>`,
2. set a status variable,
3. if next operation is selection from list then great otherwise show error message and focus back on order `<input>`.

I guess my question is simply, what is the logic? Hopefully I have included sufficient information.

The code to solve my problem is below. It was made easier by only having to apply it to one field. (Having said that I need to do some more testing as it probably won't work if they user goes back to the `hours` or `dateworked` inputs.).

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var myInputField = document.getElementById("myInput");
      var notesTextarea = document.getElementById("notes");
      var myList = document.getElementById("myUL");

      notesTextarea.addEventListener('focus', function() {
        var inputValue = myInputField.value;

        // Check if the list is currently displayed
        var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(myList);   // this gets the properties of the CSS stylings for the id myList, which is the variable of the id "myInput"
        var isListDisplayed = computedStyle.getPropertyValue('display') !== 'none';


        // Display the appropriate alert message
        if (isListDisplayed) {
            // return focus to order number input
            myInputField.focus(); 
            alert("You haven't made a selection.") ;
        }
        // If not displayed, do nothing
      });
    });
```

Comment: Instead of using the `blur` event, put the check in the `focus` event of the other inputs.

Comment: From the order _<input>_ they will enter one of `task`, `RD_activity`, or `notes` inputs. Are you saying I shoud do the check in there. If so, then makes sense. If not then it's an avenue I will explore. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was suggesting. This will allow them to click on the `<ul>` to fill in the order.

Answer (score 0):

When the input has focus and it has a value, display the filtered results.   When one of the filtered results is selected, set the value of the input equal to the the selected item.

Selecting a value will trigger the blur event for the input.  On the blur event for this input, call a function that waits a beat (avoiding the race condition between onblur firing and the value being set) and then tests to see if the input value is equal to any of the values in the list.  If not, tell the user they need to enter/select a value and add focus back to the input.

Comment: Your first sentence gives me an idea. At the moment, when a selection is made from the list , the input field is updated with that selection. But I like the idea of only showing the list when the input is in focus. At the moment it is displayed when a change has been made. That in combination with @Barmar's suggestion could work. I will try and update this post accordingly.

Comment: There is no doubt Barmar's suggestion will work, but you can get a scenario like this:  user starts typing, decides not to make a selection, clicks outside the input, pauses, then focuses another input and gets the validation message on the previous one.  I'd rather give them the message as soon as the element loses focus.  Also, if you add a form field three months from now, will you remember to add an event listener to it?

Comment: I probably wouldn't remember unless I document everything properly. But that shouldn't break the form, just interrupt the user experience. I would expect most users to get it right the first time. The users are limited to company employees so the usuage will be repetitive and they shoud learn from their entry mistakes. (The form is a timesheet).

Comment: It worked! It was made easier by the fact the inputs `task` and `RD_activity` are hidden until a selection is made. Therefore I only had to apply it to the `notes` field. Yah! I guess I post the code in "Answer Your Question".